# Inverse of $A^T Y A$

Tags: matrices, inverse

Is there a formula for the inverse of a matrix
$$ X = A^\top Y A $$
in terms of $A$ and $Y$, given that $A \in F^{m \times n}$ is full rank with $m >n$, and $Y$ is positive definite?

Comment: Is $A$ not square then? If $A$ is $m\times n$ with $m<n$ then it clearly isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks -- added the qualification that $m \geq n$.

Comment: Given that the case where $m>n$ is the non-trivial one, it may be worth restricting your question to that case. (The formula in your deleted answer certainly addresses case of $n=m$, after all.)

Comment: OK, thanks, specified the question further. The case $n=m$ is indeed straightforward.

Comment: Note that since a positive definite matrix $Y$ can be written as $Y = S^\top D S$ with $S$ orthogonal and $D$ diagonal with positive entries, we have $X = (SA)^\top D SA \equiv B^\top D B$, where $B = SA$ is a full rank $m \times n$ matrix. $X$ is invertible, because $x^\top X x = (Bx)^\top D (Bx)$, which is not zero if $x \neq 0$. This shows that the question is well-posed.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the restriction $m>n$, it need not be the case that $X=A^\top Y A$ be invertible. As a counterexample, suppose $m=2,n=1$. Then the choice $$Y=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},\; A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
yields $$X = A^\top Y A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=0$$ which is plainly not invertible.

Comment: The issue as I see it: Multiplying by an invertible matrix preserves rank, so $YA$ must have full rank. But now we're computing the product $A^\top(YA)$, and a product of full-rank rectangular matrices evidently need not have full rank.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is not turning out how I expected! A related question is this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554075/prove-that-x-top-k-x-is-invertible?rq=1. I'll think about further refining the question. As a side note: I came up with this question when thinking about the geometry of submanifolds. If $x^\mu$ are some (local) coordinates on an $m$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with metric $g_{\mu \nu}$, the induced metric on some $n$-dimensional submanifold is $h_{ab} = (\partial x^\mu/\partial y^a)(\partial x^\nu/\partial y^b) g_{\mu \nu}$, of the form

Comment: $h = e^\top g e$, or $X = A^\top Y A$, with $m > n$. I need to figure out what more I am asking from $A$. By the way, in this application, $Y$ is symmetric.

Comment: Ahah. Then I _think_ that one can do the following: $Y$ being symmetric means that it makes sense to talk about $Y$ being positive-definite (which presumably has a geometric interpretation in your case of interest). If $Y$ is PD, I think $X=A^\top Y A$ is indeed invertible. (By contrast, my $Y$ was indefinite since it had both positive/negative eigenvalues.) So that seems like a fruitful route.

Comment: Actually, looking further, it seems that Riemannian metrics are positive-definite by definition. So that seems like an entirely reasonable assumption in your context, in which case asking for the inverse of $X=A^\top Y A$ seems appropriate.

Comment: Well, it looks like I was yet again not accurate enough -- in fact I am interested in pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, which don't require a PD metric. For example flat spacetime $\mathbb{R}_\text{time} \times \mathbb{R}_\text{space}$, which, in 2 dimensions, has exactly the metric $\text{diag}(-1,1)$ that you used in your example. However, when people talk about submanifolds, they often assume that these have a well-defined "signature". I believe this comes down exactly to demanding that $X$ in our example is invertible. The reason is that a vector on the submanifold can be written

Comment: (at least locally) as $v^\mu = c^a \partial x^\mu / \partial y^a$ where $c^a$ are some real numbers and a summation over repeated indices is implied. Then the norm of this vector is $v^\mu v_\mu = c^a h_{ab} c^b$, which is required to have a specific sign throughout the submanifold (in particular not be zero anywhere). This is the demand that $h$ (or $X$) has a definite "definiteness" (or "signature") throughout the manifold, in particular it's not allowed to be zero anywhere, which means that $X$ in the question is not allowed to be singular.

That said, I will further specify the question!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. Given that $A$ is full rank means its invertible. Since $A$ is full rank, $A^T$ is also full rank (column rank = row rank). Therefore, $A^T$ is also full rank and hence invertible. Using the following result about the inverse of the product of two invertible (full rank) matrices $A$ and $B$:

$$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$$
and the fact that matrix multiplication is associative, se have that $X^{-1}$ for $X = A^T Y A$ is :

$$X^{-1} = A^{-1} Y^{-1} (A^{T})^{-1}$$

Also note that:

$$(A^{-1})^{T} = (A^T)^{-1} $$

Comment: Thanks. I agree with this proof for the particular case of square $A$, but this assumption was not stated in the question.